# How do I show that $f(x) = x^3+ax^2+c$ has exactly one negative roots?

Tags: calculus

How do I show that $f(x) = x^3+ax^2+c$ has exactly one negative roots if $a < 0$ and $ c > 0$?

I can use the the bisection technique and choose any number for a and c. But I was wondering is there are any other solutions for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f'(x)=3x^2+2ax$, which is positive if $x\leq 0$, so $f$ is increasing in $(-\infty,0)$. Also, $f(0)=c>0$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, so there exists only one negative root.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use Descartes's rule of signs:

If you substitute -x for x, you get $-x^3+ax^2+c$; and since this has only one sign change in the coefficients $[- - +]$, there is exactly one negative root.